# Can't understand strlen expression argument result

Tags: c, string, sizeof, strlen, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
int main(){
    char p[]="CALIFORNIA\n";
    char *x ="HELLO";
    printf("%lu\n",strlen(p+sizeof(p)-sizeof(x)+5) );
}
```

I searched all over but couldn't find what happens when the argument of strlen is an expression. The result is 2 for the last statement,can anyone please explain how?

Comment: Hint: it has nothing to do with `strlen()`. What does `p + sizeof p - sizeof x + 5` point to? If you can't answer then you need to understand pointers and pointer arithmetic (*and probably, `sizeof`*). Also, what does `strlen()` do?

Comment: `strlen` takes as argument a string, then it "walks" the string until \0, counting each character, and then returns that count. So the argument must be pointing to a string. It can be an expression, but the result of evaluating the expression must be a pointer to a string. Now, as Iharob, suggests, check what you are doing.

Comment: momo: Curious: Why code `"%lu"` with `strlen(p)`?  Was this found by experimentation?, code sample?  How about `'%zu"`?

Comment: Note that `sizeof(x)` will give different results depending on whether you build a 32-bit or 64-bit program.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I undertsand sizeof and and strlen. In my opinion, the expression is adding 9*sizeof(char) to starting address of p, so strlen is counting the number of characters from position 9 of p[]? which gives us the last 2 characters. Am i understanding correct now?

Comment: It is poor programming practice to include header files when the code does not use any of the contents of that header file.  Suggest removing this statement:  `#include "stdlib.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is used the pointer arithmetic. To make it more clear just run this demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *x ="HELLO";
    const size_t N = strlen( x );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu - %s\n", strlen( x + i ), x + i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
5 - HELLO
4 - ELLO
3 - LLO
2 - LO
1 - O
```

As for your example then in this statement

```
printf("%lu\n",strlen(p+sizeof(p)-sizeof(x)+5) );
```

the expression `p + sizeof( p )` has the type `char *` that is the expression yields a pointer that points one past the last element of the array object `p`.

The expression `p + sizeof( p ) - sizeof( x )` moves the pointer to the left (it seems that sizeof( x ) is equal to 8 in your system). And the expression  `p + sizeof( p ) - sizeof( x ) + 5` moves the pointer to the right.

As result the whole expression yields a pointer that pointes to the following place in the character array `p`

```
char p[]="CALIFORNIA\n";
                   ^
                   |
```

Thus the length of the string that looks like `"A\n"` is equal to `2`.